# touch should not updated `updated_at` on destroy in Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, touch, rails-models

I am working on `touch` in `Rails` but facing on issue here.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company, touch: true
end
```

But I want this should not update the `updated_at` of `company` model only when I **delete** the user but other case it **should** be. How can I do it?

Or

Is there any way to restrict this in `destroy`. Because I don't want it on `destroy`.